# Adding numbers in keys section with python dict values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created dictionary as mentioned below. from this dictionary , i am writing keys an values into a file.

```
comp_dict = { 1:
          { 'partname' : 'one' ,
           'jar': [{'soa_jar_name' : 'jar1.jar' , 'archivename' : 'archjar1.jar'},
             {'soa_jar_name' : 'jar2.jar' , 'archivename' : 'archjar2.jar'},
             {'soa_jar_name' : 'jar3.jar' , 'archivename' : 'archjar3.jar'}]},
           2:
           { 'partname' : 'two' , 'jar': 
            [{'soa_jar_name' : 'jarany.jar' , 'archivename' : 'archjarany.jar'},
              {'soa_jar_name' : 'jarmine.jar' , 'archivename' : 'archjarmine.jar'},
              {'soa_jar_name' : 'jarnew1.jar' , 'archivename' : 'archjarnew1.jar'}]}}
```

I have used below code to get the results.

```
for key in comp_dict:
for listitem in comp_dict[key]['jar']:
    inner_dict = dict(listitem)
    print('partname: {}'.format(comp_dict[key]['partname']))
    for inner_key, inner_value in inner_dict.items():            
        print('\t{}: {}'.format(inner_key, inner_value))
    print()
```

This is above code results.

```
partname: one
    soa_jar_name: jar1.jar
    archivename: archjar1.jar

partname: one
    soa_jar_name: jar2.jar
    archivename: archjar2.jar

partname: one
    soa_jar_name: jar3.jar
    archivename: archjar3.jar

partname: two
    soa_jar_name: jarany.jar
    archivename: archjarany.jar

partname: two
    soa_jar_name: jarmine.jar
    archivename: archjarmine.jar
```

But i need to add number in each keys section mentioned below.

```
partname.1: one
    soa_jar_name.1: jar1.jar
    archivename.1: archjar1.jar

partname.2: one
    soa_jar_name.2: jar2.jar
    archivename.2: archjar2.jar

partname.3: one
    soa_jar_name.3: jar3.jar
    archivename.3: archjar3.jar

partname.4: two
    soa_jar_name.4: jarany.jar
    archivename.4: archjarany.jar

partname.5: two
    soa_jar_name.5: jarmine.jar
    archivename.5: archjarmine.jar

partname.6: two
    soa_jar_name.6: jarnew1.jar
    archivename.6: archjarnew1.jar
```

Can anyone please help me here

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I need to add number in key section as  mentioned in my question

Comment: what about your code is it working or getting any error?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
count = 1
for key in comp_dict:
    for listitem in comp_dict[key]['jar']:
        inner_dict = dict(listitem)
        print(f"partname.{count}: {comp_dict[key]['partname']}")
        for inner_key, inner_value in inner_dict.items():            
            print(f"\t{inner_key}.{count}: {inner_value}")
        print()
        count+=1
```

---

```
partname.1: one
    soa_jar_name.1: jar1.jar
    archivename.1: archjar1.jar

partname.2: one
    soa_jar_name.2: jar2.jar
    archivename.2: archjar2.jar

partname.3: one
    soa_jar_name.3: jar3.jar
    archivename.3: archjar3.jar

partname.4: two
    soa_jar_name.4: jarany.jar
    archivename.4: archjarany.jar

partname.5: two
    soa_jar_name.5: jarmine.jar
    archivename.5: archjarmine.jar

partname.6: two
    soa_jar_name.6: jarnew1.jar
    archivename.6: archjarnew1.jar
```

Comment: @peter , Thanks , the result is showing with numbers added , One more questions , when i add comment heading for each section , its showing the initial comments (I.e : #comp1), i need to display #comp with count  comment on each section.

Also i want to make the display in same line . Partname is indended with second values. Can you help me here

it displaying like this

`#comp1`
`partname.1: one`
`partname.2: one`
`partname.3: one`

`#comp4`
`partname.4: two`
`partname.5: two`
`partname.6: two`

Comment: `f"#comp{count} partname.{count}: {comp_dict[key]['partname']}"` <-------

Comment: If the answer helps close the question by clicking on the tick mark. If not let me know.

Comment: @Pygril , can you please help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63021344/compare-two-dict-values-and-update-in-dict?noredirect=1#comment111445593_63021344