# compare two dict values and update in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have question to compare value between two dicts. I am comparing with "jarname""jarverion" on both dict. If its same , i need to update as "true" in dict1 section if its different version , i need to set false in dict1.Overwrite section.

```
dict2={'partname1': { 'jarversion':'1.0','jarname':'jar1.jar'},'partname2': { 'jarversion':'2.0','jarname':'jar2.jar'},'partname3': {'jarversion': '3.0','jarname':'jar3.jar'}}


dict1={1:{'partition_name' : 'avs', 'jar':[{'jarversion':'1.0','jarname':'jar1.jar'},{'jarversion':'5.0','jarname':'jar5.jar'}]},2:{'partition_name' : 'ivs', 'jar':[{'jarversion':'4.0','jarname':'jar4.jar'},{'jarversion':'2.0','jarname':'jar2.jar'}],}}
```

I comparing dict1 "jarverion""jarname" with dict2 dict using below code.

```
res=[]
for _, v in dict2.items():
    res.append(v['jarname'] + v['jarversion'])


def cmp_value( rstring='',lstring=''):
    print('rstring',rstring)
    print('lstring',lstring)
    if rstring == lstring:
        return True
    else:
        return False
for key, val in dict1.items():
        print(val)
        for eachval in res:
            if cmp_value(eachval, "%s%s"%(val['jarname'], val['jarversion'])):
                dict1[key].update({"overwrite": "true"})
                break
            else:
                dict1[key].update({"overwrite": "false"})

print (dict1)
```

But this code is not working , i am getting

```
if cmp_value(eachval, "%s%s"%(val['jarname'], val['jarversion'])):
KeyError: 'jarname'
```

Can anyone help me here.

Comment: ``dict1`` looks malformed, you might need to reformat it.

Comment: @Sushanth yes the dict1 is corrected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict2 = {'partname1': {'jarversion': '1.0', 'jarname': 'jar1.jar'},
         'partname2': {'jarversion': '2.0', 'jarname': 'jar2.jar'},
         'partname3': {'jarversion': '3.0', 'jarname': 'jar3.jar'}}

dict1 = {1: {'partition_name': 'avs',
             'jar': [{'jarversion': '1.0', 'jarname': 'jar1.jar'}, {'jarversion': '5.0', 'jarname': 'jar5.jar'}]},
         2: {'partition_name': 'ivs',
             'jar': [{'jarversion': '4.0', 'jarname': 'jar4.jar'}, {'jarversion': '2.0', 'jarname': 'jar2.jar'}], }}

res = []
for _, v in dict2.items():
    res.append(v['jarname'] + v['jarversion'])


def cmp_value(rstring='', lstring=''):
    # print('rstring', rstring)
    # print('lstring', lstring)
    if rstring == lstring:
        return True
    else:
        return False


for key, val in dict1.items():
    for eachval in res:
        for i in val['jar']:
            if cmp_value(eachval, "%s%s" % (i['jarname'], i['jarversion'])):
                i['overwrite'] = 'true'
                break
            else:
                if 'overwrite' not in i:
                    i['overwrite'] = 'false'

print(dict1)
```

output: {1: {'partition_name': 'avs', 'jar': [{'jarversion': '1.0', 'jarname': 'jar1.jar', 'overwrite': 'true'}, {'jarversion': '5.0', 'jarname': 'jar5.jar', 'overwrite': 'false'}]}, 2: {'partition_name': 'ivs', 'jar': [{'jarversion': '4.0', 'jarname': 'jar4.jar', 'overwrite': 'false'}, {'jarversion': '2.0', 'jarname': 'jar2.jar', 'overwrite': 'true'}]}}

Comment: in my code you can see for loop which solves this problem

Comment: Code is executing but Overwrite: true or false,  its not writing inside the list  of first partname

Comment: Overwrite: true or false needs to update inside {'jarversion': '1.0', 'jarname': 'jar1.jar'} each dict

Comment: if cmp_value(eachval, "%s%s" % (i['jarname'], i['jarversion'])):
                i['overwrite'] = 'true'
            else:
                i['overwrite'] = 'false' , still showing wrong . For each thing its printing "false"

Comment: rstring jar2.jar2.0
lstring jar2.jar2.0   but in result its showing  'jarname': 'jar2.jar', 'overwrite': 'false'

Comment: can you please help me here

Comment: @ DD_N0p , the test machine is on python 2.2.1. So set(res) & set(res1) wont work here any alternate solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

The `for key, val in dict1.items()` line iterates over tuples of a key (integer) and a value (dictionary).

In the line that produces the error, in the case where `key=1`, the contents of `val` is as follows:

```
{
    'partition_name' : 'avs',
    'jar': [
        {'jarversion': '1.0', 'jarname': 'jar1.jar'}, 
        {'jarversion':'5.0','jarname':'jar5.jar'}
    ]
}
```

You are asking this dictionary to return the value associated to the key `jarname`. Since the dictionary does not have that key, an error is thrown. As shown above, the only valid keys for `val` are `partition_name` and `jar`.